# Customizing Publishing Approval WorkFlow

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, publishing-site

I am using Sharepoint 2010 publishing site and trying to customize Publishing Approval workflow.

Using Designer to customize publishing approval workflow.

Is there any way to skip/bypass initiation and association forms? (like when the user click on publish/approve button the workflow should start workflow/approve and not show initiation/association form asking all fields to fill up)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [SharePoint Designer 2010 Action: Start Approval Process](http://svengillis.blogspot.com/2011/01/sharepoint-designer-2010-action-start.html)

> The Start Approval Process action behaves like a pre-built
>   workflow—the logic is already defined in the action. The action has
>   several different phases built into it that defines task behaviors,
>   task process behaviors, logging to the History Log, e-mail
>   notifications, and completion conditions. Although the action comes
>   with pre-built logic, it still needs information from you—such as the
>   users (the reviewers), the order in which the tasks are to be routed
>   to the participants—serial or parallel, the default is serial, and the
>   due dates for task completion.